# Returning cancel value to startup execution file with hex values

Tags: binary, hex, hex-editors

I'm editing the startup execution file of a program to remove an error message and automatically return the value of the "cancel" button that you would press if the message was there.

I've found the error message in the hex file where its W.R.I.T.T.E.N. .L.I.K.E. .T.H.I.S., I'm guessing because '.' is the escape key in the program so that it is interpreted as text. I then opened up the file in visual basic and discovered its hexidecimal key was 10160 and I changed the value in the file to 00 in an attempt to return 0, but that just crashed the program on startup.

What is the cancel button value that I need to put in the binary to get it to take that value automatically?